# $\nabla\times(\nabla\times \boldsymbol{A})$ using Levi-Civita

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, tensors

I want to prove that $\nabla\times(\nabla\times \boldsymbol{A}) = \nabla(\nabla\cdot\boldsymbol{A}) - \nabla^2\boldsymbol{A}$ using the Levi Civita. [This is solved considering the $i$-th component of $\nabla\times(\nabla\times \boldsymbol{A})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587405/einstein-notation-vectors/587510#587510). But I was performing the calculation and don't know where my mistake is:

\begin{align}
\nabla\times(\nabla\times \boldsymbol{A}) &= \nabla \times (\epsilon_{ijk}\hat{e}_i\nabla_jA_k) =\epsilon_{lmn}\hat{e}_l\nabla_m(\epsilon_{ijk}\hat{e}_i\nabla_jA_k)_n\\
&=\epsilon_{lmn}\hat{e}_l\nabla_m\epsilon_{njk}\nabla_jA_k = \epsilon_{lmn}\epsilon_{njk}\hat{e}_l\nabla_m\nabla_jA_k\\
&=(\delta_{lk}\delta_{mj} - \delta_{km}\delta_{lj})\hat{e}_l\nabla_m\nabla_jA_k\\
&=\hat{e}_l\nabla_m\nabla_mA_l - \hat{e}_l\nabla_m\nabla_lA_m = \nabla^2\boldsymbol{A} - \nabla(\nabla\cdot\boldsymbol{A}).
\end{align}

I get the result but with a negative sign. The only part in which I may have done things badly is when taking the levi-civita product, but I'm pretty sure that I did that correctly.

Does somebody spot my mistake? I appreciate your effort.

Comment: The bracket with the deltas appears to be the wrong way round, and this is where the errant minus sign is coming from

Comment: @DavidQuinn but if you compute $\epsilon_{lmn}\epsilon_{njk}$ with the [determinant](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369659/proof-relation-between-levi-civita-symbol-and-kronecker-deltas-in-group-theory) you get the expression of deltas I wrote.

Comment: So shouldn't that be $\delta_{lj}\delta_{mk}-\delta_{lk}\delta_{mj}$?

Comment: @DavidQuinn look, here there is a picture of how I computed the determinant: http://postimg.org/image/sswnt7qmv/

Comment: The mistake is indeed in computing the determinant. Try to expand the determinant first and then contract the $n$ index in the end (you seem to be doing both at once). For example you seem to have taken $\delta_{nn} = 1$ but this term should be $3 = \sum_{n=1}^3\delta_{nn}$.

Comment: As a check, take $l=j=1$, $m=k=2$, $n=3$. Then by definition $\epsilon_{lmn}\epsilon_{njk}=\epsilon_{123}\epsilon_{123}=1$, whereas $$\delta_{lk}\delta_{mj}-\delta_{km}\delta_{lj}={\delta_{12}\delta_{21}-\delta_{22}\delta_{11}}=-1.$$ So yours is indeed off by a minus sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to leave this question answered I will point out that @Winther's answer is correct. I took $\delta_{nn}=1$, but this term should be $3$, following the Einstein notation for summation.