# Visualizing the curl of curl

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curl

In some differential equations from phyiscs, e.g. in elastodynamics, terms with the curl of the curl of a vector field appear. For example

$(\lambda + 2 \mu) \nabla(\nabla\cdot \mathbf{x}) - \mu \nabla\times\nabla \times \mathbf{x} = \rho \ddot{\mathbf{x}}$.

Is there a way to visualize or have an intuitive/physical understanding of what is represented by the curl of a curl of a vector field.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1666286/949989) could be helpful. Not sure what can be said which you do not already know: a non zero vector field  $F$ is of the form $F=\nabla\times\nabla\times A$ if and only if it is divergence free and has an "anti-curl" $G$ that is divergence free but not rotation free: $F=\nabla \times G\,,G=\nabla\times A\,.$
A few simple examples of vector fields $A$ that have non zero $\nabla\times\nabla\times A$ are

Comment: $$
\begin{pmatrix}y^2\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\,,\begin{pmatrix}z^2\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\,,\begin{pmatrix}0\\-2xy\\0\end{pmatrix}\,,\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\-2xz\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$ 
They should not be that hard to visualize. In all those cases $\nabla\times\nabla \times A$ is $(-2,0,0)\,.$

Comment: Thanks for the input. it gives some ideas to build upon, even though I don't quite 'see' it yet:D.

Comment: I think you should first let it sink in why the [following examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorticity) have / have not curl (vorticity). This can be quite counterintuitive for the parallel flow with shear (one of my favourites). It is simply $A=(y,0,0)$ having curl $(0,0,-1)\,.$  After that you can go one level higher. Also: a relatively simple anti-curl formula you can find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4651493/on-a-certain-anticurl-operator).